# Which high quality iPhone video ressources do you know?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, uikit

I'll start:

iTunes U: The famous Stanford University offers the "iPhone Application Programming" courses online. http://itunes.stanford.edu/

I wonder if there are any more great video ressources to know, that have a reasonable quality.

Comment: Perhaps this should be grouped in with your previous question on "getting started" resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606855/which-are-the-best-iphone-dev-tutorials-on-the-net .

Answer (score 1):

The Pragmatic Bookshelf has a 5-part series entitled "Writing Your First iPhone Application": http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdiphone/writing-your-first-iphone-application

Comment: These are actually quite good, although the last one in the set will very likely be re-done when 3.0 is released. I don't know those guys, I just know that there are some significant improvements in those particular topic areas.

Answer (score 1):

http://theappleblog.com/2009/06/01/43-iphone-development-resources/ has a great section on video resources.

Answer (score 0):

When I was first getting started, [iPhone Development Central](http://www.iphonedevcentral.org/) (iphonedevcentral.org) was very helpful to me.

They have **Video Tutorials** divided into three sections: **Beginner**, **Intermediate**, and **Advanced**.